# Let $a$,$b$,$c \in R^+$, such that $abc = 1$, prove that $1 + \frac{3}{a+b+c} \ge \frac{6}{ab + bc + ca}$ .

Tags: inequality

> Let $a$,$b$,$c \in R^+$, such that $abc = 1$, prove that $1 + \frac{3}{a+b+c} \ge \frac{6}{ab + bc + ca}$ .

Clearly , $a + b + c \ge 3$ and $ab + bc + ca \ge 3$ and therefore, $(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) \ge 9$ .

How to use this information to prove the inequality correctly ?